# Entity Framework Core related data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Wondering if someone can help me out with this EF problem I seem to be having.

I've looked at the related data docs on the MS website - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data
Using their examples as a basis I've got a `Blog` object. Blogs have `Post` objects associated with them. Post objects have `Authors` associated with them.

I want to be able to retrieve the `Blog` object with `Post` object so I've got:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
                   .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                   .ToList();
```

The problem I have is that doing this means that the `Post` object has the `Author` object returned from the query too. Looking at the docs it would look like I would need to use the following to populate the `Author` object:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
                   .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                   .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
                   .ToList();
```

Is there something I'm missing that would allow me to get the blog object with the post - but not the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you overlooked the tip:

> Entity Framework Core will **automatically fix-up navigation properties
>   to any other entities** that were **previously loaded** into the **context
>   instance**. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a
>   navigation property, the **property may still be populated** if some or
>   all of the **related entities were previously loaded**.

I think this is where the confusion comes from.

The `Author` is not loaded by your query. But if it was loaded before, there are chances it is populated (since if you use Dependency Injection, the context is shared accross the whole request).

`.ThenInclude(post => post.Author)` explicitly loads the `Author`.

You can easy verify this, by creating your own scope:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public MyService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Blogs> GetBlogs()
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        using (var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>())
        {
            return context.Blogs
                          .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                          .ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The tip has been whats confusing me.